# How to implement sql "where not in" in tuple relational calculus?

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples, tuple-relational-calculus

I want to convert a sql query which has where not in clause to tuple relational calculus.Existential and Universal quantifier implements only where exists and where not exists clause so I want to know how to implement where not in?

My tables are `serves(bar,beer),frequents(drinker,bar),likes(drinker,beer)`.The following query selects the drinkers that frequent only bars that serve some beer they like.

```
select distinct f2.drinker from frequents f2 where f2.drinker not in (select f1.drinker from frequents f1 where (f1.bar,f1.drinker) not in (select f.bar,f.drinker from frequents f,serves s,likes l where l.beer=s.beer and f.bar=s.bar and f.drinker=l.drinker))
```

It's enough if someone can explain me how to implement where not in in TRC no need to convert the entire query.I am using http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~eckberg/relationalcalculusemulator.html
to check my relational calculus and convert it into sql query.

> Note:
>
> > If you use implications in your query.
>
> It does not support implication.For example implication can be
>   implemented as follows.(p==>q) can be written as (not p or q) form as
>   both are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my query with where exists and where not exists and now its easy to convert it into relational calculus.The answer is

`{T.drinker|∃f2Єfrequents (∀f1Єfrequents (∃fЄfrequents(∃sЄserves ∃lЄlikes(s.beer=l.beer^l.drinker=f.drinker^s.bar=f.bar^f1.drinker=f.drinker^f.bar=f1.bar^f2.bar=f1.bar v f2.drinker≠f1.drinker)))}`

Anyways thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

well what you are describing is `WHERE NOT EXISTS(subquery)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

let me know if thats not what you want.

---

also why dont you just change the logic of your statement to go from

WHERE drinker NOT IN (drinker) to WHERE IN(drinker=null)

INITIAL QUERY.. formatted so its easier to read

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT f2.drinker 
FROM frequents f2 
WHERE f2.drinker NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            f1.drinker 
        FROM frequents f1 
        WHERE (f1.bar,f1.drinker) NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT 
                f.bar,
                f.drinker 
            FROM frequents f,
                serves s,
                likes l 
            WHERE l.beer=s.beer AND f.bar=s.bar AND f.drinker=l.drinker
        )
    )
```

what you should be able to do is this

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT f2.drinker 
FROM frequents f2 
WHERE f2.drinker IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            f1.drinker 
        FROM frequents f1 
        WHERE f1.drinker IS NULL AND (f1.bar,f1.drinker) IN 
        (
            SELECT 
                f.bar,
                f.drinker 
            FROM frequents f,
                serves s,
                likes l 
            WHERE l.beer=s.beer AND f.bar=s.bar AND f.drinker=l.drinker AND f.drinker IS NULL
        )
    )
```

hopefully this works, i can't really test it. but the idea is instead of saying `where this is not in this` say `where this is in this where id (in subquery) is null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equal your inner query my friend,because you said `f2` is something which is not in `f1` and `f1` is something which is not in `f` and all of them got one source `frequents` and it means `f2=f` and your query returns this:

```
select f.bar,f.drinker from frequents f,serves s,likes l 
where l.beer=s.beer and f.bar=s.bar and f.drinker=l.drinker;
```

but i think this query can give you better results my friend:

```
select f.bar,f.drinker from frequents f 
left outer join serves s on  f.bar=s.bar 
left outer join likes l on l.beer=s.beer and f.drinker=l.drinker;
```

Tack a look at **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f479/6)**, it will help you to get it better.

Comment: Anyways your query also uses where not in and I need to know how to do that in relational calculus.

Comment: My Query is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f479/8  my friend,i did n't use `not in` in it.

Comment: Yeah you are right but your query doesn't do the job mine is completely different from yours.Please read my query.Thanks.